# Constructed file path to csv not recognized. But the file is there

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I want to load 134 CSVs of baby names from the social security into pandas.

First, I create a list of file names:

```
In [48]:

file_name[0:5]
Out[48]:
['yob1800.txt', 'yob1801.txt', 'yob1802.txt', 'yob1803.txt', 'yob1804.txt']
```

Then I grab the path to the folder that contains the CSVs:

```
In [67]:

file_loc = os.path.abspath("data/")
```

Finally, I use a for loop to run through the list of file names:

```
In [72]:

k = 0
for item in df_name:
    df_name[k] = pd.read_csv(file_loc+'/'+file_name[k], header=None, names=['name', 'gender', 'number_of_births'])
    k = k+1
```

But when I run the code, I get this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-72-1fe5d6b00da6> in <module>()
      1 k = 0
      2 for item in df_name:
----> 3     df_name[k] = pd.read_csv(file_loc+'/'+file_name[k], header=None, names=['name', 'sex', 'count'])
      4     k = k+1

OSError: File b'/Users/anton/data/yob1800.txt' does not exist
```

The way I read this, .read_csv() cannot find the csv file because the filepath is wrong.

However, when I run a check to see if the file path is correct, it comes back saying the file is there:

```
In [74]:

os.path.exists('/Users/anton/data/yob1880.txt')
Out[74]:
True
```

I am really stuck, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You're checking to see whether `yob1880.txt` exists, but the filename the error message refers to is `yob1800.txt`.  Can you confirm that the "right" file doesn't exist?  (Might as well rule out the easy stuff first.)

Comment: Shoot, you saw it right. The first SS csv starts in 1880. Thanks.